# Get date by utc/gmt in Android

Tags: java, android, timezone

I want to display the time in some Country, and the TimeZone is GMT+4.

```
private void loadWeather(){
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0400");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
    Date date = cal.getTime();
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
    String myDate = df.format(date);
    tv_time.setText(myDate);
}
```

I've tried this, but it gives me my time, and not the other one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're specifying the time zone just on the `Calendar` - which is *only* used to get the current instant in time, which doesn't depend on the time zone. You need to specify it on the format instead, so that it's applied when creating an appropriate text representation of that instant:

```
private void loadWeather() {
    Date date = new Date(); // This is enough; it uses the current instant.
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
        DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0400"));
    String myDate = df.format(date);
    tv_time.setText(myDate);
}
```

Or to inline even more:

```
private void loadWeather() {
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
        DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0400"));
    tv_time.setText(df.format(new Date()));
}
```

(This is assuming you really do want the short date/time format using the current locale.)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to display the time in some Country, and the TimeZone is GMT+4.

GMT+4 is **not a time zone**. A time zone is represented as *Region/City* e.g. *Europe/London*. Check the [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for more examples. GMT+4 means time zone **offset** i.e. 4 hours ahead of UTC and therefore, in order to get the equivalent date-time at UTC, one has to subtract 4 hours from the date-time at GMT+4.

### GMT+4 is not the standard way to represent time zone offset

The standard format is `+/-HH:mm:ss` or `Z` which refers to `+00:00` offset. In most cases, you will see `+/-HH:mm` e.g. `+06:00`. Check [this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC) to learn more about it.

### java.time

The `java.util` date-time API and their corresponding parsing/formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) was released as part of the **Java 8 standard library** which supplanted the legacy date-time API and since then it is strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

### Solution using `java.time`

To represent a date-time with time zone **offset**, the Java 8+ standard library provides [`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.of("+04:00"));
        System.out.println(now);

        // The corresponding date-time at UTC
        System.out.println(now.toInstant());
        // Alternatively
        System.out.println(now.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    }
}
```

**The output from a sample run**:

```
2023-02-04T14:08:58.657721+04:00
2023-02-04T10:08:58.657721Z
2023-02-04T10:08:58.657721Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/vK9Gdx)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` as below and set the `TimeZone` to the `SimpleDateFormat` object...I think, you will get the problem right.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0400"));

    String date = dateFormatGmt.format(calendar.getTime());
```